# RegEx matching space not starting/ending with char

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, regex-negation

I need to split the text to the words but I also need to ignore the & character. That means for example the word "h & m" has stay together. Regex must also work in JavaScript and node.js.

I used `/(?!&)\s(?!&)/g`. But that ignore space with & character only at end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot split (and you cannot split since there is no look-behind in JS), you need to match:

```
\S+(?:\s&\s\S+)*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ1wO3/2)

Code:

```js
var re = /(\S+(?:\s&\s\S+)*)/g; 
var str = 'H & M shopping mall';
var m = str.match(re);
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = m;
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: This regex will allow multiple `word & word & word...`, if you want to limit it to just 2 words, replace the `*` with `?`: `var re = /\S+(?:\s&\s\S+)?/g;`. And if there may be multiple spaces between words, also use `+` after `\s`: `var re = /\S+(?:\s+&\s+\S+)*/g;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use look ahead and look behind... (just add `<` to your current regex)

```
/(?<!&)\s(?!&)/g
   ^
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yW8bG7/1)

Explanation:

- All spaces whose previous character is not `&`.. `(?<!&)` and next character is also not `&`.. `(?!&)`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Lookbehinds are not supported by the JS, so i can't use it in node.js application.

Comment: `/(?<!&)\s(?!&)/g` is clearly a JavaScript literal notation regex, and the test is performed against the PCRE library. So, the test passes, but not for JS: https://regex101.com/r/yW8bG7/2

Comment: @stribizhev..you are right..also it was intentional because question did not have any JS tag before posting the answer.. thats why I assumed PCRE :)